# Request Header not being sent as a parameter to API calls

Tags: api, networking, cors, access-token, request-headers

I was trying to make an API call to another domain, which has no-cors enabled.

The API call was made something like this:

```
let url = `https:sampleApiUrl?params=xxxx`;
            console.log("hitting dashboard url")
            get(url, token)
                .then((resp) => {
                    console.log("resp", resp)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
```

This API call, subsequently calls a 'get' method:

```
const get = (url, authToken) => {
return baseFetch(url, 'get', false, authToken).then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.json();
    } else {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
});
```

}

Now, this get method calls a baseFetch method:

```
const baseFetch = (url, verb, body, authToken) => {
const request = {
    method: verb,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'credentials': 'include'
    },
    mode: 'cors'
}

if (authToken){
    // adding x-access-token in the request header
    request.headers['x-access-token'] = authToken;
}

if (body){
    request.body = JSON.stringify(body);
}

return fetch(url, request);
```

}

Now, when this API call is requested, I can't see the "x-access-token" populated in the browser network call.

[No x-access-token in request-headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEZo8.png)

Also, I am not sure why I get status code 204 in response.
Calling this API from postman and directly from browser or calling as a curl request, returns the correct response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking  at the image,  you are looking at the headers for pre flight OPTIONS method and not the GET method.  The pre flght request is generated by the browser and it never has any custom header.  therefore it did not have the x-access-token in its headers.